# how to transfering stored procedure and functions from one database to another database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am using sql server 2005 and i want to transfer my all stored procedures and functions to another newly created database. How i can do this by writing one stored procedure. Can any one tell me help me regarding this?

Comment: Not sure if this is could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945325/syncing-stored-procedures-between-two-databases?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use generate script feature and run it on another database.
Right click on your database --> tasks--> generate script choose your objects and get the scrip then run it on the other database.

Comment: I want through Stored procedures only.

Comment: Generate script add it into stored procedure body.

Comment: i have 200 stored procedures in one database. i want to move this by executing a single stored procedure.Wether it is possible?

Comment: Note that there is no mechanism that you can move procedures . you should recreate them. with generate script feature you can generate script for all of your procedures just in one time. and execute it so all you have other side.

Comment: I got the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631009/no-answer-for-copy-stored-procedure-one-database-to-another

Comment: But also generate script is more standard.

Comment: if i do like this what problem i may get...?

Comment: There is no problem but generate script is a featute that ssms considers for this requests. So ir is more accurate.